# error in my simpsons rule integration

Tags: python, integration, simpsons-rule

I have written the following code to use simpson's rule to integrate an arbitrary function, in my case, sin(x):

```
import math


delta_x=(x2-x1)/N

def simpson(x1,x2,f,N):
    sum=0
    i=1
    for i in range(1,N+1):

        sum+=f(x1+i*delta_x)

    sum1=(3*delta_x)*sum

    return(sum1)

print(simpson(0,math.pi,math.sin(x),100))
```

however I get the error 'float object not callable' on the sum+=f(x1+i*delta_x) line. Anyone know what could be wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: `sum` is a built-in function - I'd recommend against defining any variable to override a builtin!

Answer (score 1):

The `f` argument to your function is supposed to be a function. `math.sin(x)` doesn't return a function, it calculates the sin of `x` and returns that number. `simpson()` is then trying to call it as a function.

You should just pass `math.sin`, it will be called by `simpson()` in the loop.

```
print(simpson(0,math.pi,math.sin,100))
```